# validate long variable if null

Tags: java

I am having difficultie while validating a long variable if it is null.
The Code which I am using is :

```
long late_in= latein_hours.getTime();
```

It will show an error that java null pointer exception. So how can I validate if it is null then make it equal to zero.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
long late_in = 0;
if(latein_hours!=null){
    late_in= latein_hours.getTime();
}
```

Primitive can't be null, only reference to object can hold `null` value

Answer (score 9):

A `long` can’t be `null`: if you don't set a value, is automatically set to 0.

If you want a variable that can be null (for example if not initialized), you must use `Long` (look the case).
`Long` is like a container for `long` that can be `null`.

```
Long latein_hours;
long late_in;
if(latein_hours!=null){
    late_in= latein_hours.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The long isn't null. `latein_hours` is.
If this is intentional, then you can do:

```
long late_in = latein_hours == null ? 0 : latein_hours.getTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if `latein_hours` is `null` or if `getTime()` returns a `Long` which is `null`. Either way you just need to check for the null like this:

```
long late_in = 0;
if (latein_hours != null && latein_hours.getTime() != null) {
    late_in = latein_hours.getTime(); //auto unboxing
}
else {
    // was null
}
```

It's the second case which often trips people up when using autounboxing, you do get some null pointer exceptions in code you thought of as just doing some maths with primitives.

Comment: -1: Assuming `latein_hours` is a `java.util.Date` object, `getTime()` returns a primitive `long` not a wrapper `Long`

Comment: +1 - Down-voting someone for not making a dangerous assumption stinks.

Comment: I shouldn't write comments before I vote. Yes a downvote would be too harsh and yes I would have taken it back, if I ever had voted it down. (and if you don't believe me - look at my rep)

Answer (score -1):

```
if(latein_hours!=null) {
    long late_in= latein_hours.getTime();
}
```

You will get a null pointer exception, if you invoke anything on the null object. i.e 
if

```
latein_hours = null;
latein_hours.getTime(); // NullPointerException
```

Comment: you can not use != operator for Long